# Text over image displaced when publsihed

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a banner image on a report with three labels, some with params in them, on top of it.
It all looks fine in design mode but when I save and view it the text is then displaced above and below the image.  How do I stop it doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

1. Insert a Rectangle the same size as your banner image and set the BackgroundImage property value to your banner image.
2. Add your text boxes over the top of your rectangle.

Comment: Seems you can't get the image to resize when it's a `BackgroundImage` on the `Rectangle`, however.

Comment: One thing to note is that images will **only** export to Excel if using the image component from the Toolbox. If the image is set using a BackgroundImage property then it will not export to Excel. According to MSDN: _Background images for report items are ignored because Excel does not support background images for individual cells._ See [Excel Limitations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx#ExcelLimitations)

Comment: It works in SSRS environment itself, but when exporting to MS word the layout is broken again. Then I think the answer by @Jamie J would be safer

Answer (score 3):

Insert a Rectangle the same size as your banner image and set the BackgroundImage property value to your banner image.
Add your text boxes over the top of your rectangle.

That worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

SSRS doesn't support superimposing data onto an image very well.

I believe the only way to do this is to set the image as the `BackgroundImage` of a Report item that has this property, such as a text box. This limits how you can place things on the image, though.

I suppose you could do a 1990's style split of the image into many pieces and set those as different background images of textboxes arranged appropriately. Ugly, but I can't think of anything better.